# Create multiple Objects from the same class

Tags: php

I've got a very simple question but I don't get it. I've got a class with a few values looking like this:

```
class test_one{
    private $value1, $value2;

    public function __construct($value1,$value2){
        $this->$value1 = $value1;
        $this->$value2 = $value2;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create twenty objects of this class.

The Code in C# is looking like this:

```
ref = new test_one[20];
```

So my question is: **how can I create 20 objects of the same class and save them in a reference so I can adress them by their Index?**

Comment: You need to use loop

Comment: your assigning syntax is wrong

Comment: `$this->value1 = $value1;$this->value2 = $value2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

```
<?php
class test_one{
    private $value1, $value2;

    public function __construct($value1,$value2){
        $this->value1 = $value1;
        $this->value2 = $value2;
    }
}

for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++) {
    $var = "object" . $i;
    $$var = new test_one($value1 = $i, $value2 = $i*$i);
}

 // show, say, object20
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($object20);
 echo '</pre>';
```

output:

```
test_one Object
(
    [value1:test_one:private] => 
    [value2:test_one:private] => 
    [20] => 20
    [400] => 400
)
```

Comment: `$value1 = $i, $value2 = $i*$i` redundant assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop, as already said in comments. Simple loop can be:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 20) {
    $arr_of_objects[] = new test_one();
}
```

Also, as already noticed in comments **too**, assigning values to class properties is done without `$`:

```
public function __construct($value1,$value2){
    $this->value1 = $value1;
    $this->value2 = $value2;
    //----^ no $ here
}
```